# When I Remove Asyncio from this code i get the error An error occurred while sending messages: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, discord

After removing `asyncio` from my code, I got:

```
An error occurred while sending messages: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'request'
```

This is the code I'm trying to make faster.

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
import asyncio

# Initialize bot A
intents_a = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents_a.typing = False
intents_a.presences = False
intents_a.message_content = True

botA = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents_a, chunk_guilds_at_startup=False)
botA_token = token  # Replace with the token of botA

@botA.event
async def on_ready():
    print('[BOT A] Created.')

# Define the tokens for the controlled bots
controlled_bot_tokens = [
    "token",
    "token",
    "token"
    # Add more controlled bot tokens as needed
]

# Initialize and store controlled bots
controlled_bot_instances = {}

for token in controlled_bot_tokens:
    controlled_bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents_a, chunk_guilds_at_startup=False)
    controlled_bot.token = token  # Store the token for later use
    controlled_bot_instances[token] = controlled_bot

@botA.command()
async def spam(ctx, user_mention: str, *, message: str):
    try:
        for controlled_bot in controlled_bot_instances.values():
            # Extract user ID from the mention
            user_id = int(user_mention.strip("<@!>"))
            target_user = controlled_bot.get_user(user_id) or await controlled_bot.fetch_user(user_id)

            if target_user:
                await target_user.send(message)
                await ctx.send(f"{controlled_bot.user.name} sent a message to {target_user.mention}: {message}")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"Could not find the mentioned user.")
    except nextcord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send(f"Could not send a message to the mentioned user. Check bot permissions.")
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"An error occurred while sending messages: {str(e)}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(botA.start(botA_token))

# Start the controlled bots
for controlled_bot in controlled_bot_instances.values():
    loop.create_task(controlled_bot.start(controlled_bot.token))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(botA.logout())
    for controlled_bot in controlled_bot_instances.values():
        loop.run_until_complete(controlled_bot.logout())
```